# python - Creating counting grid from set of points

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a dataset of longitudes/latitudes as follows:

```
id,spp,lon,lat
1a,sp1,1,9
1b,sp1,3,11
1c,sp1,6,12
2a,sp2,1,9
2b,sp2,1,10
2c,sp2,3,10
2d,sp2,4,11
2e,sp2,5,12
2f,sp2,6,12
3a,sp3,4,13
3b,sp3,5,11
3c,sp3,8,8
4a,sp4,4,12
4b,sp4,6,11
4c,sp4,7,8
5a,sp5,8,8
5b,sp5,7,6
5c,sp5,8,2
6a,sp6,8,8
6b,sp6,7,5
6c,sp6,8,3
```

From such data, I want to generate a grid like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

which gives the number of data records in each cell of the grid, using variable "spp" as a categorical (grouping) factor.

From this grid, I then want to create a heat map, superimposed on a geographical map, so that I end up with something like the figure below.

[image]

I (finally) managed to write some code which does what I want.

Here it is:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib import cm as cmap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

#read input data
with open('testdata.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    headers = reader.next()
    input_data = list(reader)

#grid dimensions with one-degree resolution
lat_inf, lon_inf = 0, 0
lat_sup, lon_sup = 90, 360
resolution = 1

latitude, longitude = [], []
latitude = range(lat_inf, lat_sup, resolution)
longitude = range(lon_inf, lon_sup, resolution)

#create output grid
output_grid = []
for i in latitude:
   output_grid.append([])
   for j in longitude:
       output_grid[i].append(0)

#traverse the input_data evaluating the lat, lon coordinates
#summing +1 in the output_grid[latitude][longitude].
for row in input_data:
   lat = int(row[2]) 
   lon = int(row[3]) 
   #sp = row[1]

   #check its indexes
   i_lat = latitude.index(lat)
   i_lon = longitude.index(lon)

   #increase counter
   output_grid[i_lat][i_lon] += 1

output_grid = np.array(output_grid, np.int16)

#create map
m = Basemap()
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)

#display image
im = m.imshow(output_grid.transpose(), cmap='summer', origin='lower', aspect='auto', interpolation='none')
m.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

It (mostly) works, but te problem is that the grid image is not being displayed correctly: it appears too small, in the lower left corner of the map, as shown in the figure below).

[image]

Also, is there a way to change the backgound color of the image grid, other than fiddling with Matplotlib colormaps?

Any hints, ideas, suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Always provide a [mcve] of the issue. Otherwise you cannot expect to get more than some general solution.

Comment: I fail to see why my example is not "minimal, complete and verifiable". If I did not get an answer, it is because either nobody knows the answer.

Comment: Oh, ok sorry, if the above is really the complete code you are lacking the information about the coordinates. Which coordinate does each pixel in the grid have?

Answer (score 1):

Drawing an image on a basemap might be possible, but you would need to fiddle with the coordinates and the extent to get it at the right position.

Better use a `pcolormesh` which supports non-equally spaced grids and hence is well suited for different projections. What you need is then not only your data, but also a grid. This grid defines the location of each point of the data. 
Before using the grid, you need to transform it to the basemap coordinate system, so if `lons,lats = np.meshgrid(..., ...)` is the grid, and `m = Basemap(..)`, the transformed grid is

```
X, Y = m(lons,lats)
```

This can then be supplied to `pcolormesh`

```
m.pcolormesh(X,Y,data)
```

A complete example, where we have a data array of shape (60x40) which we want to reside in the longitude range between -10 and 50 degrees and in the latitude range between -20 and 20 degrees:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

data = np.random.rand(40,60)

lons,lats = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10,50,data.shape[1]+1),
                        np.linspace(-20,20,data.shape[0]+1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
m = Basemap(projection='merc', ax=ax, lat_0=0.,lon_0=0.,
            llcrnrlon=-179.,llcrnrlat=-80.,urcrnrlon=170.,urcrnrlat=80.)
m.drawcoastlines()
X, Y = m(lons,lats)
pc = m.pcolormesh(X,Y,data,cmap='RdBu_r')

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-60,61,20),labels=[1,1,0,1])
m.drawmeridians([-90,-10,50,90],labels=[1,1,0,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you *very much* for your answer, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. It was helpful with meshgrid and pcolormesh. However, I have not yet figured out how to correctly adjust my data to the map.

Comment: I do have problems figuring out what the coordinates should be for your example. That's why I provided a generic example. If you can answer the question from the comments "Which coordinate does each pixel in the grid have?" one may probably help you further.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. So, the reason I did not replied to th!t question is that I did not understand it... What do you mean by pixel coordinates of the grid? In my example, I have a 90 rows (lats) x 360 columns (lons), so that it is a one-degree resolution.

Comment: So in the answer above I have 40 rows and 60 columns and a 1 degree resolution. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The [doc for Basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html) says

> Calling a Basemap class instance with the arguments lon, lat will
>   convert lon/lat (in degrees) to x/y map projection coordinates (in
>   meters). The inverse transformation is done if the optional keyword
>   inverse is set to True.

So, you need to covert your data to degrees of lat and lon, pass those to Basemap, and use what is returned to you to plot your locations.

The color you're getting is the default color for "cool" (see the color bar to the right of your plot). I'm not sure how to change it, but I think there should be arguments you can pass to MPL routines to tell it which color to use for "cool" and which to use for "warm".

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to plot locations, I want to display an image over the map. Also, the color map is changed by means of the parameter 'cmap' in the imshow call (as a matter of fact, my exemple uses what MPL calls a 'summer' colormap). But I what I would really like to know is if there is some tricky way of displaying the image with a 'transparent' backgound.

Comment: When you say "transparent", I think that just means the cool color (where your data isn't) should match the default color of the map. I think you could get that effect by specifying the background color you're expecting as the cool color. As far as scaling your image to the map, it seems like maybe you could get that by fiddling with the aspect and extent args to imshow(). Sorry I misunderstood what you're trying to do.

Comment: Already spent a long time fiddling with the args of imshow to no avail.